# How to create password protected zip files using log4j ? Is it possible through log4j?

Tags: java, xml, logging, log4j, zip

Can we create password protected zip file using log4j? If yes, how we can do it? I tried for zipping the file using log4j. it is working fine. but i am unable to find anywhere to create password protected zip file.